# Django internationalisation within template inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am doing a Django app for which I simply want to have a translated page title. Using Django templating mechanism, I have a `base.html` which starts like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyProject - {% block title %}Welcome{% endblock title %}</title>

...
```

Now, for my "about" page, I want to extend the base. Hence my `about.html` looks like:

```
{% extends 'myproject/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

....
```

Ans this is where I start to be confused. Of course `{{ title }}` is a variable which can be translated in the code of my `views.py`:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
def about(request):
  context = RequestContext(request)
  context_dict = {'title': _("About")}
  return render_to_response('myproject/about.html', context_dict, context)
```

Except it doesn't work. Of course, I removed the browser cache, reprocess makemessages and compilemessages and all that stuff a bazillions time. There is something I dont understand. Changing `{{ title }}` for `{% trans title %}` doesn't work either, nor with `{% blocktrans %}...`. I simply don't get it. Should I translate my title elsewhere altogether? There must be a simpler solution to that simple problem, no? Maybe I am all wrong.

Any hint, suggestion, or solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. There was a typo in the paths inside the LOCALE_PATHS bundle in the settings... Of course, the translations couldn't be found. Now it works. A little error message from Django would have been helpful, but I couldn't find it. Oh well...

Comment: never used i18n before. Does it translate 'About' into your language? French?